# How to bring OS X native Digital Camera RAW support from 10.11 El Capitan to 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I work on an old Mac Pro and Mavericks 10.9 seems the best system for me.
However Apple is not updating Digital Camera RAW support for Mavericks and so does not support my new digital camera, a Nikon1 J5 that is supported in El Capitan.

A lot of programs that make catalogues are based on Apples native Digital Camera RAW support.

So I am looking for a solution to get native support for my new camera on Mavericks.

I have the idea that native support is handled by two files in the OS X system:

```
/system/Library/coreservices/RawCamera.bundle 
/system/Library/coreservices/RawCameraSupport.bundle
```

I tried to replace these files in Mavericks with those of El Capitan.

But my mission was not successful.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: idk the answer to your question, but how old is old? No issues on a Pro 5,1 running El Capitan here. Also have a 3,1 which [due to pure laziness] is still on Yosemite, still no issues.

Comment: I have also been experimenting with adding RAW file support in Mavericks for the Olympus EM-5 Mk II, which has only appeared natively with more recent MacOS versions. Exactly what symptoms or errors did you experience with the wholesale replacement of those two RawCamera bundle files? In other words, how was your mission not successful?

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with an older OS is going to leave you out of the loop on updates included in new versions. This is unavoidable if you are not willing to upgrade. For what it's worth, every older system that I have upgraded to El Capitan has seen some performance increases, in at least one case it was a significant bump in usability (early unibody MacBook that was barely usable in Yosemite is working beautifully in El Capitan).

Do a full system backup and give the newer OS a shot. It is difficult but not impossible to downgrade. If you can swap in a spare hard drive, and install from there, you won't risk your current setup just to check whether you can live with the changes implemented in 10.11.

Comment: Dr Nixon and Hello Tetsujin, thanks for your reply;
As you know it is all about details if you work on a computer the way you want and Apples newest OSX is usually only stable in it final version.
I have an upgraded macpro3.1- with usb3 card and an old wacom intuos 3. the USB card stops working in el Capitan and the wacom has some unexpected scrolling.These two items work best in OSX 10.9.5 and are important to me. Also the first version of El Capitan gave me a non resonsive finder with crashes- the 11.1 did install better. ( i always start from a clean install)

Comment: Makes sense - the hardware prevents software update. I guess you have to decide what is more painful, cobbling together an unsupported backport of the Camera Raw, buying a new El Capitan-compatible Wacom, or abandoning your current workflow in favor of something that works with Nikon-supplied Camera RAW support...

Comment: dr Nixon, my macpro is from 2008 and no longer supported,because Apple has to move on... so painful is that in a short time i am not able to download 10.11.6 anymore and that Apple programs are not longer supported on 10.11... Apple tells me it is time to buy something new...still the machine is much faster than most of the new apple gear- it is a shame

Comment: 2013 MBP, acquired used, with RAM maxed out, is SIGNIFICANTLY faster than the 2007 MBP I used prevously. And much faster than the 2011 17" MBP my wife is using. You don't need to go all the way to the new systems with SSDs to see an improvement.